# filtering null values from an RDD<Vector> spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, filter, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

I have a dataset of doubles in form of JavaRDD. I want to remove the rows(vector) containing null values. I was going to use filter function in order to do that but cannot figure out how to to do it. I am pretty new to spark and mllib and would really appreciate it if you could help me out.This is how my parsed data looks like:

```
String path = "data.txt";
JavaRDD<String> data = sc.textFile(path);
JavaRDD<Vector> parsedData = data.map(
  new Function<String, Vector>() {
    public Vector call(String s) {
      String[] sarray = s.split(" ");
      double[] values = new double[sarray.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < sarray.length; i++)
        values[i] = Double.parseDouble(sarray[i]);
      return Vectors.dense(values);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: There is no NULL in the vector. If there were some NULL for double, the `Double.parseDouble` will throw exception. There can be only empty vector.

Answer (score 0):

Checking a vector[i] element against null might put you in the clear?

And then perform an operation similar to vector.remove(n). Where "n" is the element to be removed from the vector.

Comment: Well  actually i don't know how to access the elements of an RDD (here a vector), and also i would like to remove the whole vector if there is a null in it,...

Comment: Would it be possible for you to give some sense as to the contents of the text file you intend to work on?

The following link could give you some clues:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/quick-start.html#standalone-applications. Your example code seems to be from https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/mllib-clustering.html#examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
Vector values = Vectors.dense(new double[vector_length]);
    parsedData = parsedData.filter((Vector s) -> {
         return !s.equals(Vectors.dense(new double[vector_length]));
    });
```

As mentioned in the comments, RDD vector can't be NULL. However, you might want to get red of empty (Zero) vectors utilizing the filter method. This can be done by creating an empty vector and filtering it out.